# Inverse z transform - help

Tags: transform

How can I find inverse z transform of $$X(z)=\frac{5}{(z-2)^{2}}$$ ?

It is known that x[n] is causal.

EDIT: Here is what I have done. Since signal x(n) is causal, convergence of z transform of that signal will be outside of circle with radius r:

[image]

We have in bracket sum which represents z transform of signal:

[image]

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: wow, two poles outside the unit circle.  this should be interesting.

Comment: even wolfram knows the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+z+transform+%285%2F%28z-2%29%5E2%29)...

Comment: Thanks jojek, but I'm interested in how to get final solution. Wolfram can't show me that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r},\quad |r|<1\tag{1}$$

Due to convergence of (1) (for $|r|<1$) you can take the derivative with respect to $r$ by taking the element-wise derivatives of the left-hand side. Equating the derivatives of both sides of (1) gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nr^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nr^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)r^n=\frac{1}{(1-r)^2},\quad |r|<1\tag{2}$$

With $r=az^{-1}$ you get the following $\mathcal{Z}$-transform relation:

$$(n+1)a^nu[n]\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{(1-az^{-1})^2}=\frac{z^2}{(z-a)^2}\tag{3}$$

where $u[n]$ is the unit step sequence.
With the time-shifting property of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties)) you get the following pair:

$$(n-1)a^{n-2}u[n-2]\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{(z-a)^2}\tag{4}$$

With (4) you immediately get

$$\frac{5}{(z-2)^2}\Longleftrightarrow 5(n-1)2^{n-2}u[n-2]$$

Of course, all of this is only valid inside the region of convergence, i.e. for $|z|>a=2$.

Comment: hey Matt, looks like etf believes in the stick more than the carrot.  at least you got a check mark for your effort.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I guess the OP wanted to see *how* to get the result. And that's indeed not shown in many basic DSP texts.

Answer (score 0):

note, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_transform)

$$ \mathcal{Z}\left\{ n a^n u[n] \right\} = \frac{az^{-1} }{ (1-a z^{-1})^2 } $$

see if you can make your problem fit that form.  (gonna get a funky result because $a=2$.)

Comment: Hi. I didn't solved it yet...